# Remove the default shadow on right and bottom of input type text

Tags: html, css

I have few input fields on which i have given some border rounding. The problem I am facing is that a shadow appears on the right and bottom of the field. I want to control the width of it along with color and some other properties. I have used `box shadow` properties but that creates another shadow instead of removing or styling this one. So what is this little thing if it's not a box shadow and how to style it..

```css
.options {
    width:40px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style:outset;
    box-shadow: none; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" name="1" value="3" readonly>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuhk0Lg8/)

Comment: Offhand I'd say it was the border - http://jsfiddle.net/kuhk0Lg8/1/

Comment: border seems to be the problem. If you provide border:none;background:grey you can see the difference.http://jsfiddle.net/kuhk0Lg8/2/

Comment: Its due to `border-style:outset;`. Try removing `border-style` and `box-shadow`

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior for [border-style:outset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style). You should overwrite it with something like solid.

```css
.options {
    width:40px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="options" id="3" name="1" value="3" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `border:none;` or add `border:1px solid grey;` on your class

```
.options {
    width:40px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style:outset;
    box-shadow: none;   
    border:none;
}
```

or

```
.options {
        width:40px;
        text-align:center; 
        margin-left:30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-style:outset;
        box-shadow: none;   
        border:1px solid grey;
    }
```